# Extracting real and imaginary numbers from a complex number

Tags: real-numbers

How can I get the real number and the imaginary number from: $$\frac{3+i}{5-12i}$$

Comment: Oh, you mean $(3+i)/(5-12i)$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\dfrac{a+ib}{c+id}=\dfrac{(a+ib)(c-id)}{(c+id)(c-id)}=\dfrac{ac+bd+i(bc-ad)}{c^2+d^2}$$

Comment: I reached $27+41i/169$ and i'm not sure how canIi get the real and imaginary number from it

Comment: @DinRevah, $$\dfrac{x+iy}n=\dfrac xn+i\dfrac yn$$ for $x,y,n$ are real numbers

Comment: @labbhattacharjee That's true even if they're not real

Comment: @columbus8myhw, Do you mean $n=0$?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{3+i}{5-12i}=$$

$$\left|\frac{3+i}{5-12i}\right|e^{\arg\left(\frac{3+i}{5-12i}\right)i}=$$

$$\frac{\left|3+i\right|}{\left|5-12i\right|}e^{\arg\left(\frac{3}{169}+\frac{41}{169}i\right)i}=$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{3^2+1^2}}{\sqrt{5^2+12^2}}e^{\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{41}{3}\right)i}=$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{10}}{\sqrt{169}}e^{\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{41}{3}\right)i}=$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{10}}{13}e^{\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{41}{3}\right)i}=$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{10}}{13}\left(\cos\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{41}{3}\right)\right)+\sin\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{41}{3}\right)\right)i\right)=$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{10}}{13}\cos\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{41}{3}\right)\right)+\frac{\sqrt{10}}{13}\sin\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{41}{3}\right)\right)i=$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{10}}{13}*\frac{3}{13\sqrt{10}}+\frac{\sqrt{10}}{13}*\frac{41}{13\sqrt{10}}i$$

$$\frac{3}{169}+\frac{41}{169}i$$

Comment: This is the long answer, but if you want to understand it, this the way to calculate it!

Comment: That seems like overkill, just to show that $3+\frac i5-12i=3-\frac{59}5i$! Besides, turns out he meant $\frac{3+i}{5-12i}$, anyway.

Comment: @columbus8myhw now it's right!

Comment: Still overkill, to be honest.